# How do I populate a field based on a select value on Laravel Nova?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-nova

I am having trouble in Laravel Nova. I want to populate a field using the value of a SELECT.

```
Select::make('Product')->options(\App\Product::pluck('name', 'price'))->rules('required')
```

I get the name of a product as a value and the price as the key. Would it be possible then to display the price in another field?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would give you name and name price so the label would show the Name and Price

```
Select::make('Product')->options(\App\Product::select(DB::Raw('CONCAT(name," ",price) as label'),'name')->get()->pluck('name','label')->toArray())->rules('required');
```